# remove duplicate character in string and make unique string

Tags: javascript

I wrote a code and it works fine, But is there any easy and more handy way to implement that using javascript RegExp Object or any other way ?

```js
function removeDuplicateChar(str) {
 var temp = [], j = 0;
 var arr = str.split("");
 arr.sort();

 for(var i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
  if(arr[i] != arr[i+1]) {
   temp[j++] = arr[i];
  }
 }
 temp[j++] = arr[arr.length-1];

 for(var i = 0; i < j; i++) {
  arr[i] = temp[i];
 }

 return arr.join("").substring(0,j);
}
console.log(removeDuplicateChar("Rasikawef dfv dd"));
```

Comment: `const removeDuplicateChar = s => [...new Set(s)].join("");` - note that i didn't pay too much attention to performance, i just made a short alternative.

Comment: since it's working fine and you're looking for improvement, i think you should post this in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you like one liners? Minimal code can be very efficient. Compare the following:

**With sets and list comprehension:**

```js
const remDup= e => [...new Set(e)].sort().join("");
console.log(remDup("Rasikawef dfv dd"))
```

**With reduce:**

```js
const remDup= s=> s.split("").sort().reduce((a,b)=>(a[a.length-1]!=b)?(a+b):a,"")
console.log(remDup("Rasikawef dfv dd"))
```

**With filter:**

```js
const remDup= s=> s.split("").filter((e,i,f)=>f.indexOf(e)==i).sort().join("")
console.log(remDup("Rasikawef dfv dd"))
```

**With map:**

```js
const remDup= s=> s.split("").map((c,i,o)=>(o.indexOf(c)==i)?c:"").sort().join("")
console.log(remDup("Rasikawef dfv dd"))
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let removeDuplicate = (string) => string.split("").reduce((s, c) => {
  if (s) {
    if (-1 == s.indexOf(c)) return s + c;
  }
  return s;
});

console.log(removeDuplicate("banana")); // => ban

console.log(removeDuplicate("Rasikawef dfv dd")); // => Rasikwef dv
```